# Build upload to TestFlight has been unsuccessful due to some error related to 'ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage'

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

[check error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxgYD.png**)

ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public symbols in : _UlIFontFeatureSelectorldentifierkKey_ForNewSwiftAPI,
UlIFontFeatureTypeldentifierkKey_ForNewSwiftAPI. If method names in your source code
match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent
this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of
the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so,
they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at

If anyone knows of a solution to this and has had such a problem in the past, Please help me to resolve.Detailed error image is mentioned.

Thank you.**

Comment: The solution is quite simple–don't use the method that Apple pointed out. If it's not something familiar, just try searching in your project–probably some third-party dependency uses it internally.

Comment: – lazarevzubov I have searched, But nothing like that in my project.

Comment: Have you asked Apple reviewers? They're also people and can help (and even make mistakes).